# How to recursively set a style value for DOM children with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Propose the following DOM:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
         Inside
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how many child levels there are within a given parent node. Now I would like to recursively downscale the width for each child level using JQuery.

For the top level  the width would be 100%
For the second level  it would be 100%*0.9
For the third level  it would be (100%*0.9)*0.9

Whats the straightforward solution to this?

Comment: It makes sense to untag this question from [jquery] since it is purely a CSS problem.

Answer (score 3):

`width` in CSS is calculated relative to the parent element. Therefore you can set the top-level `div` to `100%` width and all child `div` elements to `90%` width by using the `>` child selector, like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  margin: 2px;
}

div > div {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Inside
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion you can use `calc()` to calculate width and pass children of the current element to next recursion level.

```js
function style(div, scale = 1) {
  div.css({width: `calc(100% * ${scale})`})
  const children = div.children('div');
  if (children.length) style(children, scale * 0.9)
}

const div = $("body > div");
style(div)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      Inside
    </div>

    <div>
      <div>Inside</div>
      <div>Inside</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```